# using File.Open(parameters and File.Read(path).Last()

Tags: c#, io

i'm working on a project in c# and need to be able to read the last line of a text file in use before processing for other activities. here is my code sample. The File.Open works fine by itself and so does the ReadLines(path).Last(). Together, they don't work. I'm new to C# and would appreciate any help given.  Thanks

```
 string g = "C:\\zebra\\file.txt";

 File.Open (g, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);                                    

string  file_name = File.ReadLines(g).Last();// error of being unable to access file because it's in use

            Thread.Sleep(50);

            Name.Text = file_name.Substring(13); 
            ID.Text = file_name.Substring(8, 5);
```

Comment: If you are going to use `ReadLines`, you don't need to `File.Open`, if you want to use `File.Open`, don't use `ReadLines`.

Comment: Thanks but I used the File.Open because the file is periodically written to by another application linked with my project. Although notepad is able to open on the fly so I used that so that I could access it alongside the other program.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that each of the two calls -- `File.Open` and `File.ReadLines` -- uses its own file system resources "under the hood", and you're not properly disposing of the open file connection before calling `File.Readlines` on the same file.

My suggestion is to get rid of the `File.Open` call entirely, it's not needed (unless you're using it in some way you haven't shown us).  `File.Readlines` wraps the entire disposable pattern and takes care of of cleaning up everything for you, i.e. the open file stream.

If you *are* using the file stream created by `File.Open` in a way that you haven't shown us, then use a `using` statement like this:

```
using (FileStream file = File.Open(g, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    // do your stuff here with your `file` object.
}

// Now do your subsequent/unrelated operations on the file:

string  file_name = File.ReadLines(g).Last();
```

That will take care of cleaning up your resources even if an exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks. The code is what i put up earlier on in my question.There isn't any thing else related that I have not shown. I tried using the using statement you suggested all the same and now it throws an exception of  not finding a System.IO in the debug folder of the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `File.ReadAllLines` method, which will return an array of the file's lines. This can be used to get the last line as you know the length of the array

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(g);
string file_name = lines[lines.GetUpperBound(0)];
```

This avoid the need to use `File.Open` at all, as the method opens, reads, and closes the file all in one. **This will only work if your file is small enough to be held in memory**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My file is just a few kb in size reaching a max of about 5kb as the other program writes to it. That was the reason for which I used the File.open because I needed to read it's contents periodically even as the other program writes to it also periodically. is there someway I can achieve this?

Comment: This will be good for that, as the file will be closed immediately after being read, and still store the contents of the file in this array

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only problem with using the code is that it still sees the text file as being in use by the other running application without the File.Open attached.